# UIViewController.navigationController becomes nil

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I bumped into a problem where `UIViewController.navigationController` becomes `nil` and I'm desperately trying to find an answer to this one.

The `UINavigationController` gets setup in the application delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootView" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.rootViewController];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

When the `RootViewController` is appearing, the `self.navigationController` member is set and I can use it to hide the navigation bar, like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog( @"self = %@, self.navigationController = %@", self, self.navigationController );
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

The debug output shows values for `self` and `self.navigationController`.

When a button is clicked in this controller, `self` remains the same value indeed but `self.navigationController` is now `nil`:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
        NSLog( @"self = %@, self.navigationController = %@", self, self.navigationController );
        // here, self.navigationController is nil, so
        // [self.navigationController pushViewController:...] doesn't work :-(
}
```

I've seen dozens of questions regarding this problem and the answer is always that the `UIViewController` is not part of a `UINavigationController`. Since accessing the `navigationController` in `viewWillAppear` works fine, I believe something else must be going on. Do you have any pointers? I'll happily provide more detail if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows that you are only using the navigationController's view but just pray that navigationController life is handled by some magic hand which is not the case.

You need someone to be the explicit owner of the navigationController here.

In fact, the following line:

```
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

seems to indicate that what you want is for the window's rootViewController to be navigationController:

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

But also, it seems that the application's delegate is to be an owner of navigationController as well so navigationController should, in fact, be an ivar of your app's delegate.

In short, fix your object graph (and it will coincidentally do the extra retain you manually did and fix your bug)

Comment: In-depth explanation by an Apple engineer! Thanks for that. I've happily accepted your answer as the undoubtedly correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the app delegate:

```
[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:NO];
```

the rootviewcontroller is actually `UINavigationController` if you po to debug it. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with a nil view controller and found that it was not connected properly in storyboard to the app delegate.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I am not using Storyboards here, though, since I need to target iOS 4.x. Also, it's not the view controller which is nil, but the navigationController.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it helps to formulate the question just to find the solution some minutes later.

I fell prey to ARC, I guess. Once I retained the `UINavigationController` in the application delegate, it worked fine.

Comment: the solution works but there is a good reason why you had to do that.